# Why am I getting this Uncaught Type Error when accessing this JSON data?

Tags: jquery, json

I am requesting data from the Guardian API and am getting the following error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'thumbnail' of undefined

I know that fields is a property of an element in the results array (I have only included the first result for brevity) and that it is also an object with its own properties but I'm not sure why fields is not being identified.

I'm accessing the data using the jQuery Ajax method.

jQuery

```
   $.ajax({
            url: "http://content.guardianapis.com/football/liverpool?show-factboxes=all&edition=UK&show-most-viewed=true&date-id=date%2Flast7days",
            data: {
                // enter your developer api key here
                apikey: "hidden",
                // the type of data you're expecting back from the api
                _accept: "application/json"
            },
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function(data) {

                for (var i = 0; i < data.response.results.length; i++) {

                    var link = data.response.results[i].webUrl;
                    var image = data.response.results[i].fields.thumbnail;
                    var head = data.response.results[i].fields.headline;

                    $('body').append('<a href="' + link + '"><h1>' + head + '</h1></a>');
                    $('body').append('<img src="' + image + '"">');
                } 

            },
            error: function() {
                 console.log('error');
            }
        });
```

---

The data.

JSON

```
{
  "response": {
    "status": "ok",
    "userTier": "free",
    "total": 15,
    "startIndex": 1,
    "pageSize": 10,
    "currentPage": 1,
    "pages": 2,
    "orderBy": "newest",
    "tag": {
      "id": "football/liverpool",
      "type": "keyword",
      "webTitle": "Liverpool",
      "webUrl": "http://www.theguardian.com/football/liverpool",
      "apiUrl": "http://content.guardianapis.com/football/liverpool",
      "sectionId": "football",
      "sectionName": "Football"
    },
    "results": [
      {
        "id": "football/gallery/2014/feb/23/premier-league-liverpool-newcastle",
        "sectionId": "football",
        "sectionName": "Football",
        "webPublicationDate": "2014-02-23T16:34:00Z",
        "webTitle": "Premier League: Sunday's matches – in pictures",
        "webUrl": "http://www.theguardian.com/football/gallery/2014/feb/23/premier-league-liverpool-newcastle",
        "apiUrl": "http://content.guardianapis.com/football/gallery/2014/feb/23/premier-league-liverpool-newcastle",
        "fields": {
          "trailText": "<p>The best images from a seven-goal thriller at Anfield between Liverpool and Swansea and a less exciting one-goal game at St James Park featuring Newcastle and Aston Villa</p>",
          "headline": "Premier League: Sunday's matches – in pictures",
          "showInRelatedContent": "true",
          "lastModified": "2014-02-23T17:53:39Z",
          "hasStoryPackage": "false",
          "score": "1.0",
          "standfirst": "The best images from a seven-goal thriller at Anfield between Liverpool and Swansea and a less exciting one-goal game at St James Park featuring Newcastle and Aston Villa",
          "shortUrl": "http://gu.com/p/3n265",
          "thumbnail": "http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2014/2/23/1393170159591/Liverpools-Henderson-004.jpg",
          "commentable": "false",
          "allowUgc": "false",
          "isPremoderated": "false",
          "byline": "Jonny Weeks",
          "publication": "theguardian.com",
          "shouldHideAdverts": "false",
          "liveBloggingNow": "false",
          "commentCloseDate": "2014-02-26T16:34:34Z"
        }
      },
```

Comment: Are you sure that there isn't an item in the results array that happens not to have a 'fields' attribute?

Comment: I just searched for a smaller set of results on the Guardian explorer and made sure they all had the fields attribute. Same error.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing a parameter in the URL 'show-fields=all'.